# How to set classpath for JAR file paermanenlty

Tags: java, jdbc, environment-variables, classpath

There are thousands of materials on the internet. I followed some of the trusted sources but still I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I'll quickly show you what I've tried:

Added **classpath** in environment variables

[image]

[image]

Then I tried adding with command prompt also with this command:

`set classpath=%classpath%;C:Users\320050772\Documents\task-tracker\*.jar`

[image]

But still I'm getting this error:

[image]

Either I'm not doing this correctly or I'm missing an important step here. Please correct me.

Here's is my **DataService.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DataService {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","scott");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
            while(rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `java -cp %classpath% DataService` or even `java -cp .;C:\Users\320050772\Documents\task-tracker\ojdbc14.jar DataService` - also check `jar -tvf C:\Users\320050772\Documents\task-tracker\ojdbc14.jar` (must include the `OracleDriver.class`)

Answer (score 1):

From the java docs:

> Class path entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or JAR files) nor the asterisk (*) wildcard character are ignored.

My advise is to replace "*.jar" with concrete .jar - File references. Please double check the output of `echo %CLASSPATH%` (Windows) or `echo $CLASSPATH` (Linux and related OS)

[Java Documentation 1.8: Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Comment: I'm sorry Gernot. I'm still getting same error. And the output of `echo %classpath%` is: `.;C:\Users\320050772\Documents\task-tracker\ojdbc14.jar;`

Comment: Just try and use only C:Users\320050772\Documents\task-tracker\ without any jar

Comment: @MagdalenaFairfax Now I'm getting another error: `Error: Could not find or load main class DataService`.

Comment: @MagdalenaFairfax. I'm doing only 2 steps: `javac DataService.java` and then `java DataService`

I've added my code in the question.

Comment: I usually get this error when there are different java versions. Check your default java version in command line with java - version and see if it is the same as the one you are using to compile the code. Also you can check your manifest file.